# use react-joyride in multiple child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I want to use `react-joyride` in my application but there is a problem. I have breakdown my component into `Navbar` and `SideNavigation`. They are separate child component. Now that I want to use `react-joyride` in both first in `SideNavigation` and then the last step be in `Navbar`. How can I do it so?

Here is my code

```
class AgentDashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      roles: [],
      joyrideOverlay: true,
      joyrideType: "continuous",
      isReady: false,
      isRunning: false,
      stepIndex: 0,
      steps: [],
      selector: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
      isReady: true,
      isRunning: true,
    });
  }


  addSteps(steps) {
    let newSteps = steps;
    if (!Array.isArray(newSteps)) {
      newSteps = [newSteps];
    }

    if (!newSteps.length) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState(currentState => {
      currentState.steps = currentState.steps.concat(newSteps);
      return currentState;
    });
  }

  callback(data) {
    this.setState({
      selector: data.type === "tooltip:before" ? data.step.selector : ""
    });
  }

  next() {
    this.joyride.next();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      isReady,
      isRunning,
      joyrideOverlay,
      joyrideType,
      selector,
      stepIndex,
      steps
    } = this.state;
    let html;
    if (isReady) {
      html = (
        <div>
          <Joyride
            ref={c => (this.joyride = c)}
            callback={data => this.callback(data)}
            debug={false}
            disableOverlay={selector === ".card-tickets"}
            locale={{
              back: <span>Back</span>,
              close: <span>Close</span>,
              last: <span>Last</span>,
              next: <span>Next</span>,
              skip: <span>Skip</span>
            }}
            run={isRunning}
            showOverlay={joyrideOverlay}
            showSkipButton={true}
            showStepsProgress={true}
            stepIndex={stepIndex}
            steps={steps}
            type={joyrideType}
          />
          <TopNavigation
            username={this.state.username ? this.state.username : ""}
            }
            roles={this.state.roles}
          />
          <main className="imp">
            <SideNavigation
              currentNav={this.props.location.pathname.substring(1)}
              addSteps={steps => this.addSteps(steps)}
              selector={selector}
              next={() => this.next()}
            />
          </main>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {html}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AgentDashboard);
```

**SideNavigation.js**

```
const sideMenus = [
  {
    menu: "My Property",
    link: "imp/dashboard/my-properties",
    icon: "icon-hotel",
    class: "hotel-selector"
  },
  {
    menu: "My IMP",
    link: "imp/dashboard/my-imps",
    icon: "icon-people-outline",
    class: "imp-selector"
  },
];

class SideNavigation extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    const steps = [
      {
        title: "Trigger Action",
        text: "It can be click",
        selector: ".imp-dashboard",
        position: "right",
        type: "hover",
      },
      {
        title: "Advance customization",
        text:
          "You can set individual styling options for beacons and tooltips.",
        selector: ".hotel-selector",
        position: "bottom",
        allowClicksThruHole: true,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: "#ccc",
          mainColor: "#000",
          header: {
            color: "#f04",
            fontSize: "3rem",
            textAlign: "center"
          },
          footer: {
            display: "none"
          },
          beacon: {
            inner: "#000",
            outer: "#000"
          }
        }
      }
    ];
    this.props.addSteps(steps);
  }

  handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { next } = this.props;
    next();
  };

  render() {
    const { currentNav, selector } = this.props;
    const menuToShow = sideMenus.map(menuItem =>
      <Menu.Item key={menuItem.link} className={menuItem.class}>
        <NavLink
          activeClassName={currentNav.includes(menuItem.link) ? "active" : ""}
          to={`/${menuItem.link}`}
        >
          <i className={menuItem.icon} />
          <span>
            {menuItem.menu}
          </span>
        </NavLink>
      </Menu.Item>
    );
    return (
      <Sidebar.Pushable>
        <Sidebar
          as={Menu}
          width="thin"
          visible
          icon="labeled"
          vertical
          inverted
        >
          <Menu.Item name="dashboard" className="imp-dashboard">
            <NavLink
              activeClassName={currentNav === "imp/dashboard" ? "active" : ""}
              to="/imp/dashboard"
            >
              <i className="icon-activity" />
              <span>Dashboard</span>
            </NavLink>
          </Menu.Item>
          {menuToShow}
        </Sidebar>
        <Sidebar.Pusher>
          <Routes />
        </Sidebar.Pusher>
      </Sidebar.Pushable>
    );
  }
}
```

Do you think it is possible to use react-joyride with these kind of component breakdown/structure? I am totally blank on how can I use it. Can anyone guide me, please? I managed to write the above code where I don't get any error nor I see any intro part working when button is clicked. Have i missed anything?

Here is the code in gist for better readability

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bc0121ab23652513c2639a0aa55c4390

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with this kind if component breakdown(Top and side navigation).
The important thing is properly configuring the "arrayOfSteps" for joyride. Importantly, to configure the "selector" property of steps in joyride component.

For example, the array of steps can travel through top and side navigation tags. Something like:

```
   {
  title: 'First Step',
  text: 'Start using the <strong>joyride</strong>',
  selector: '#first-top_menu',
  position: 'bottom-left',
  type: 'hover',
  isFixed: true,
  // optional styling
  style:{
   .....
    }
},
{
  title: 'Second Step',
  text: 'Start using the <strong>joyride</strong>',
  selector: '#second-top_menu',
  position: 'bottom-left',
  type: 'hover',
  isFixed: true,
  // optional styling
  style:{
   .....
    }
},
{
  title: 'Third Step',
  text: 'Start using the <strong>joyride</strong>',
  selector: '#first-side_menu',
  position: 'bottom-left',
  type: 'hover',
  isFixed: true,
  // optional styling
  style:{
   .....
    }
},
```

Comment: But its not working. I see the button that is created from joyride which when clicked nothing happens

Comment: Do I have to copy paste the css of joyride either?

Comment: Yes. You need the css of joyride (it is provided as .scss file. You may need to convert to .css file). Also try setting allowClicksThruHole:true.